# Pseudo-class selectors not highlighted in sublime text

Tags: sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting

When I use pseudo-class selectors in sublime text, the syntax does not highlight the pseudo-class selectors (mine is plain white, see screenshot).

Everything works fine, it's just not highlighted.

**Any idea on how I can enable it? Thanks!**

Here's a screenshot of the syntax and the extensions/plugins I've installed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by [writing a custom color scheme](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html) or using an [existing color scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/color%20scheme) that colors the pseudo-class selectors the way you like.

There's no simple way to color the selectors. Extensive documentation on writing color schemes can be found [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html).

If you feel a color other white should be default in the color scheme that you're using, you can [open an issue](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages).